# Serial Equivalence

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, computer-science

Could someone please explain to me in clear terms as to what Serial Equivalence is? I have had a look but can't seem to find a clear definition of what it actually means?

My current understanding is where the order of transactions does not matter as they are serially equivalent and the outcome is the same? If this in correct please explain what this actually means.

Comment: More along the lines of if you can completely separate two interleaved transactions, and the end result is the same as when they were interleaved, they're serially equivalent. The order of operations is still relevant, so you can't reorder the transactions, just the times the individual components occur at.

Comment: Ah I see, so it's not really to do with the transaction order, but the order in which the content of the transaction is done?

Comment: Yeah. Changing the order of a transaction would probably affect its results. e.g... updating a bank account balance without first retrieving the balance to make sure there's sufficient funds in it.

Comment: So it's like this: if you have 2 transactions and the contents are put together and the output is the same as if they are apart then they are serially equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

One of these should do it:

> Used in DISTRIBUTED SYSTEM technology to describe the effect that a number of parallel or nested TRANSACTIONS have on the state of such a system. When such transactions are carried out their effect is said to be serially equivalent if the state of the system is the same as if they were carried out sequentially.

Source: http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100455897?rskey=KQEjV6&result=0&q=serial%20equivalence

> Two transactions are serial if all the
>   operations in one transaction precede
>   the operations in the other.

Source: http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/distrubutedSite/dist-sys/ds-node220.html

> We say that an interleaving of two
>   blocks is serially equivalent, if the
>   result is equivalent to an execution
>   in which one block was executed
>   entirely before the other.

Source: http://www.itu.dk/courses/INP/E2001/Materiale/Concurrency/www/p3.php

Also, take a look at the bottom of page 6 and further on of this PDF document:
http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/distsys/Slides/lecture7.pdf

Especially take a look at the the examples given in the PDF document and at the 3rd link.

Comment: So is it along the lines of, if you have 2 transactions and the contents are put together and the output is the same as if they are apart then they were serially equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you are right.Recall, write/write and read/write are conflicting. Read/read operations are not conflicting.
For two transactions to be serially equivalent, all pairs of conflicting operations must execute in the same order on all objects they both access.
Each transaction should write the same data object immediately after reading it or updation of data object should done before accessing by another transaction .

Comment: Can you give some real time example.